# CCL Save-Application, Clisp Saveinitmem, Issues

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, executable, clisp, ccl

On ccl on mac os x 10.9 i am having a problem cretaing executables.

`(save-application "/full/path/to/saved-app" :prepend-kernel t)` double clicking the produced executable file enters on terminal showing very long errors starting with a one like error: problems loadiing bundle:can't determine class name and ending with the kernel debugger options.

On **ccl** on **windows** i simply define a function and do the same above to save executable, later i can double click the output file it runs and remembers my defined function, **ccl** on **mac** dont remember also when i save image and load it to kernel manually.

on the **clisp** side, it **creates executable** on my **mac**, and on some **widows** installations it **creates executable** but i **cannot launch executable**, it gives an error prompt window saying something like

> application failed to start because libreadline6.dll not found.
>   restarting application may solve the problem

but don't.

What are the problems here, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the DLL cannot be found.
So, unless the OS is lying to us (which I wouldn't put past it, alas) the solution is

1. locate `libreadline6.dll`
2. add that directory to `PATH` or move/copy/link `libreadline6.dll` to a directory which is in `PATH`
3. *or* run your new image with an augmented `PATH` (either by creating an application shortcut or by running from the command line `PATH=/path/to/libreadline6.dll:$PATH /my/new/lisp/image`)